# Can I make an executable jar with "build-info" by "Spring Boot Maven Plugin"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to make an executable jar file with "Spring Boot Maven Plugin".

Usually, I can do this by setting ["repackage".](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html) goal in my pom.xml file was set like this.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And my build command is like this:

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage
```

This works, but I want to have **META-INF/build-info.properties** in the jar file.

By having this file, I can check build info in my springboot application, so I want to have it.

To generate "**META-INF/build-info.properties**" file, I need to set ["build-info"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/build-info.html) goal.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Well now I am in a dilemma because

1. Setting "repackage" goal -> an **executable** jar **without** "META-INF/build-info.properties"
2. Setting "build-info" goal -> an **inexecutable** jar **with** "META-INF/build-info.properties"

I want to have an **executable** jar **with** "META-INF/build-info.properties".

I am pretty new to this maven process. Is there anyone who can help me?

---

### SOLVED

I solved this issue. The problem was `spring-boot-maven-plugin` was in the wrong place. It was inside `<pluginManagement>`. I moved this plugin to `<plugins>`

Like @Mark Bramnik answered, I can set both goal settings in pom.xml, and `mvn clean package` command is enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple goals of the same plugin.
So you can probably do something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: usually you just use `mvn package` or `mvn clean package` if you want to clean the target directory before building the app. This way you trigger the default "lifecycle" that has phases like compilation, test execution. packaging, etc. Plugin's goals are attached to these phases so that maven can rule out the correct way of building the project by itself from your "declarative" declarations (you tell maven what do you want to build, and maven resolved HOW to do that right).

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Unfortunately, `mvn package` didn't do the trick, because it doesn't make an executable jar. I think `repackage` goal should be set?

Comment: I"ve set two goals in the answer - build info and repackage... Try to examine `mvn package` output and see whether both goals of spring-boot-maven-plugin are executed (build-info and repackage), Which comes first?

Comment: Well, actually, `mvn package` command doesn't seem to call any of goal. This command doesn't seem to call "spring-boot-maven-plugin" while packaging.
Now I have "Inexecutable" jar without "META-INF/build-info.properties"

Comment: Then the issue is somewhere else in your pom, maybe you can post the whole pom in the question or something? In general repackage goal is supposed to create a jar that can be run by `java -jar <jar>`  I assume this is something you refer to as  an "executable" jar.

Comment: You were correct!
My <plugin> setting for "spring-boot-maven-plugin" was  inside `<pluginManagement>`, not `<plugins>`. After I moved it to inside `<plugins>`, both goals are working like a magic.
Thank you so much for your advice!